# How to move enemy characters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I have random enemy characters spawned into a map using Unity 3D.  The enemies have rigid bodies with gravity enabled.  I use MovePosition to move them around the map (in the 'forward' direction) in the Update() method and select a random rotation so they 'wander' around randomly.

Because gravity is enabled when they walk up or down hills on the island, it all works correctly (they stick to the terrain).

The problem arises when I fire an arrow at them. Sometimes they start floating upwards into the sky, despite gravity being turned on.

I tried using AddForce() instead, after reading that may be more appropriate for non-kinematic rigidbodies, but movement became very erratic and so went back to movePosition.

Any ideas how I can stop them floating upwards when hit by arrows sometimes?  I'm guessing having enemies walk around randomly and then be able to be hit by arrows must be a fairly common requirement for game designers, but not been able to find a best practice method to use anywhere on google?

```
void Update() {

    ...

    rigidBody.MovePosition(rigidBody.position + movementDirection * 0.4f * Time.deltaTime);

    ...

}
```

Comment: What does an arrow hit do that would affect physics? This feels like you have some bug in the code that handles this hit

Comment: Since you are working on physics. How much mass are your bullet and enemies? Seems like you might have assigned less mass to your enemy than bullets hence they are floating away. it's might help to show your code and properties assigned to your objects.

Comment: Also, try constricting movement to the Y-axis in rigid-body.

Comment: I think your code needs to be moved to `FixedUpdate()`? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

Comment: Do both, the enemies and arrows, have colliders active when the arrow hit the enemy? This can cause them to push eachother up.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was due to internal inertia on the enemy objects - just found this video during lunch.  Another unityism... so frustrating, but hopefully this answer helps out others in the future:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maIAiSRBEdE

It turned out Fixed constraints were being ignored by unity because of the internal inertia being set on the objects rigid body.